# partial derivative of integral question.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Question about exercise 5.11 in Shaum's outline for vector analysis, 2nd edition:

regarding this section of equation:

$\phi(x,y,z)=\int \limits_{x_0}^x F_1(x, y_0, z_0) dx + \int \limits_{y_0}^y F_2(x,y,z_0)~ dy + \int \limits_{z_0}^z F_3(x,y,z) dz$

taking partial derivative with respect to x:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\phi(x,y,z)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg(\int \limits_{x_0}^x F_1(x, y_0, z_0) dx + \int \limits_{y_0}^y F_2(x,y,z_0)~ dy + \int \limits_{z_0}^z F_3(x,y,z) dz\bigg)$

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\phi(x,y,z)=F_1(x,y_0,z_0) + \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg(\int \limits_{y_0}^y F_2(x,y,z_0)~ dy\bigg) + \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\bigg(\int \limits_{z_0}^z F_3(x,y,z)~ dz\bigg)$

now subtituting: $\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial y}$  and $\frac{\partial F_3}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial z}$

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\phi(x,y,z)= F_1(x,y_0,z_0) + F_1(x,y,z_0)\bigg|^y_{y_0} + F_1(x,y,z) \bigg|^z_{z_0}$

**why does the first term on the right hand side, equal $F_1(x,y_0,z_0)$ instead of $F_1(x,y_0,z_0)\bigg|^x_{x_0}$ with a vertical bar?**

Comment: These integrals aren't well-defined. You're using the same variable name for one of the bounds and for the integration variable.

Comment: that's just the way they wrote it in shaum's outline...Let me see if i can fix it in the comments...  End Point on a line integral curve is (x,y,z) and start point is $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$.

Comment: if you define the integral nicely the first equation is: $\phi(x,y,z)=\int \limits_{x_0}^x F_1(t, y_0, z_0) dt + \int \limits_{y_0}^y F_2(x,t,z_0)~ dt + \int \limits_{z_0}^z F_3(x,y,t) dt$  basically, the curve is go in x direction, then go in y direction, then go in z direction.

Comment: It's hard to say why the result isn't something it isn't. You'd have to tell us why you think that's what it should be; then we can say what's wrong about that reasoning.

Comment: umm... because schaum's outline says it has 480 fully solved problems to study?

Comment: That may be a misunderstanding. You ask why the result isn't a particular result. Without knowing why you think it should be that particular result, it's hard to answer that. We can try to guess why you might think it should be that, but it would be much more effective if you told us. Presumably you came up with that alternative result for some reason.

Comment: I'm just showing my surprise, i thought it should be this but, they said it was that instead... now i need to figure out what i did wrong...

Comment: Exactly. And we can't help you figure out what you did wrong if you don't show us what you did and just state the result. If I say "I thought $2^5$ should be $2$ because $2^5=(1+1)^5=1^5+1^5=1+1=2$", you can tell me where I went wrong. If I just say "Why is $2^5$ $32$, I thought it should be $2$", what can you tell me?

Comment: what i did was this: $\int \limits^a_b f'(x) dx =  f(x) \bigg|^a_b$  not sure why this doesn't apply to the first term.

Comment: Ah, OK. Then the problem was indeed, as I suspected, caused by the muddled notation in the book. Try to do that with the corrected version that you posted in a comment above. You'll find that the derivative refers to a different variable than the integral.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101887/discussion-between-pico-and-joriki).

Answer (score 1):

They're leaving out the step of moving the derivative under the integral sign.

First, $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\displaystyle\int_{x_0}^x F_1(t,y_0,z_0)\,dt = F_1(x,y_0,z_0)$ by the usual Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Next, 
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int_{y_0}^y F_2(x,t,z_0)\,dt &= \int_{y_0}^y \frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x}(x,t,z_0)\,dt = \int_{y_0}^y \frac{\partial F_1}{\partial y}(x,t,z_0)\,dt \\ &= F_1(x,y,z_0) - F_1(x,y_0,z_0),
\end{align*}
by the (other) Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: But if you move the derivative under “first,” inside of integral, wouldn’t it be f1(x,y0,z0) -f1(x0,y0,z0). Instead of just f1(x,y0,z0)?  Not sure why this one is special..

Comment: No, no. We're using what's often called the *first* Fundamental Theorem of Calculus here, differentiating with respect to the upper limit of the integral.  This says that $\frac d{dx} \int_a^x f(t)\,dt = f(x)$ whenever $f$ is continuous at $x$. In the other cases, we actually use the *second* Fundamental Theorem, which tells us that $\int_a^b f'(t)\,dt = f(b)-f(a)$. (Some texts reverse the numbering here.)

Comment: Ok ...I  think I get it...   second fundamental law doesn’t apply to second term because upper limit of integral doesn’t match partial derivative variable...but it does apply to first term because it’s the same variable...

Comment: There you go. That's correct.